# sql nested inner join only returning 1 result

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building a Chatapplication that's a bit like the facebookchat. I have users,conversations and messages. All 3 have their own tables. For now I try to get all converstations containing a certain user and the latest message of the conversation.

I tried this query, but in a fact I only get 1 row back, but there are more rows matching

```
SELECT conversations.id as converid,
       messages.from as messageauthor,
       messages.message as message 
FROM conversations INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM messages 
                               ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1) as messages 
ON messages.conversationid=conversations.id 
WHERE user1=3 
OR user2=3
```

When I do i.e.

```
SELECT conversations.id as converid,
           messages.from as messageauthor 
FROM conversations INNER JOIN  messages 
ON messages.conversationid=conversations.id 
WHERE user1=3 
OR user2=3
```

I get all results, for sure, and when I check the converid's I get 3 unique Id's, so at least there are 3 converstations going on with userid 3. So the top query should also return 3. Now I don't understand why it only returns 1 row. Does the `limit 1` from the nested query affect the whole query?

Looking forward for some pointers...

Comment: Seems to be the nested limit.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1` - will only return the most recent message.  If you want only 1 message per conversation you need to use different logic.

Comment: I changed the nested LIMIT to 10, and it returns 10 unique results now.

Comment: if your result from the inner query (messages) table only returns one result (limit 1). then unless you have more than one conversation with the same message id, a maximum of one message per conversation will show up. To test this, you can run the sub-query on its own and see what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The `limit 1` affects the subquery, so it is only returning one row.  So, there is only one match.

What is the issue with this query (your second query, but formatted differently):

```
SELECT c.id as converid, m.from as messageauthor 
FROM conversations c INNER JOIN 
     messages m
     ON m.conversationid=c.id 
WHERE user1=3 OR user2=3;
```

I see, you want the latest message.  Try calculating it and joining back in:

```
SELECT c.id as converid, m.from as messageauthor 
FROM conversations c INNER JOIN 
     messages m
     ON m.conversationid=c.id join
     (select m.conversationid, max(date) as maxdate
      from messages m
      group by m.conversationid
     ) mmax
     on mmax.conversationid = m.conversationid and m.date = mmax.maxdate
WHERE user1=3 OR user2=3;
```

Comment: That it would return all messages, that's a bit "too much" data

Comment: Actually, that will only take 1 message per conversation (see: `m.date = mmax.maxdate`).  If you have an id field in the message table you could use that instead.

Comment: I tried this query and got "Unknown column 'm.conversationid' in 'field list'" Anyway this is a very new approach for me to this problem. So I will read a bit more now about those sql functions to understand whats going on in this query as it seems to be a better approach than mine ...